# Role based menu using JSF sentinel theme Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsf, primefaces

I am working on an existing project i want to add a new parent menu and sub menu, all I can see is that the menus are added on a DB table called menu and mapped to a table call role_menu but I keep on getting a null pointer exception, what am I missing ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4imKR.png)

1. added the menu to DB
2. MApped to a role
   3 what else should I do
   am using Java and JSF
   Thanks in advance guys.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck5HH.png)

Comment: We cannot help without way more info than you have provided.  if you are getting a NullPointerException you should be able to narrow down where that is happening an figure out what is NULL.  And if it is coming from a database this sounds like it was something custom coded at your company as coming from a DB is not default Primefaces Sentinel out of the box.

Comment: It seems, from the last screenshot, that userController is null, can you check that class annotation or how do you define that bean?

Comment: Hi WoAinii, I am trying to add a new menu for the admin user I only get this error when i add a new menu in the  DB and map it to this user so basically its working but I am unable to add more menus and am not sure  why this is happening

Comment: Then it seems as Melloware said, an error in the custom code, from db. If you want some more help post a fully reproducible example.